# Why df -h not showing partition mounted?

Tags: shell, centos, command-line, partition

Why do I need to run "df -h" whith sudo to show my lvm partition mounted that I just added?

When I run the command with sudo I get this result :

```
/dev/mapper/centos00-root       4,9G    1,4G  3,6G  28% /
devtmpfs                        1,9G       0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           1,9G    4,0K  1,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           1,9G    8,6M  1,9G   1% /run
tmpfs                           1,9G       0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                       969M    119M  784M  14% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos00-opt         15G     41M   14G   1% /opt
/dev/mapper/centos00-var         20G    129M   18G   1% /var
/dev/mapper/centos00-home       4,7G     20M  4,5G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/postgres-database   118G     36G   77G  32% /var/lib/pgsql/9.6
tmpfs                           380M       0  380M   0% /run/user/16777220
```

And when I run the commande as a normal user I get the same result, but without the line :

```
/dev/mapper/postgres-database   118G     36G   77G  32% /var/lib/pgsql/9.6
```

I have other servers and I do not have this problem.
I use CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708

#### UPDATE #1

Here's the output for the commands asked in the comments:

```
$ findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION /dev/mapper/postgres-database
TARGET             PROPAGATION
/var/lib/pgsql/9.6 shared
```

I tried with another target and I have the same answer:

```
$ findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION /dev/mapper/centos00-var
TARGET PROPAGATION
/var   shared
```

Comment: What does `findmnt -o TARGET,PROPAGATION /dev/mapper/postgres-database` tell you ? Just a wild guess,but does the propagation column result in `private` ?

Answer (score 1):

`df` retrieves filesystem information (used/free/total space) using `statfs()`.  The input parameter for `statfs()` is a path - a file or directory name.  The output of `statfs()` is the information for the filesystem which the file belongs to.

If you do not have permission to open a path on a specific filesystem, then you cannot get the filesystem information.

The postgres data directory is only readable by specific users and groups.  Otherwise, any user could bypass the read access controls which were configured inside the database.