# Mount command finishes successully, but disk is not mounted

Tags: mount

We're trying to mount a disk, but even though the mount command finishes successfully, the disk isn't mounted

```
bart@test:/$ sudo mount -v /data
mount: /dev/sdc1 mounted on /data.
bart@test:/$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.4G     0  3.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           697M  688K  697M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        29G  3.0G   26G  11% /
tmpfs           3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      105M  3.4M  102M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1        14G   41M   13G   1% /mnt
tmpfs           697M     0  697M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Here is the relevant line in /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=f7c675d9-6b7c-4f96-a26f-5991df9b7cac    /data   ext4   defaults 1   2
```

Any idea what we could be missing?

`/data` is an empty folder with root permissions.

Output of `blkid`:

```
/dev/sdb1: UUID="7e15008f-4654-4f1d-8aec-1f233c68e5ea" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3dbf34a8-01"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="cloudimg-rootfs" UUID="21b294f1-25bd-4265-9c4e-d6e4aeb57e97" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bcf3ccb8-bce6-4498-93fb-1b9bd59fc81c"
/dev/sda15: LABEL="UEFI" UUID="5CC4-10AB" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="ee783a1a-c5d0-42d9-b874-71796971f49b"
/dev/sda14: PARTUUID="2081abbc-a4ba-496a-b391-07952095f65d"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="f7c675d9-6b7c-4f96-a26f-5991df9b7cac" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="54aa8864-01"
```

[Solved]: So while we tried this very thing multiple times yesterday, we just executed a reboot, and now the device is there. It probably got fixed by changes we made by pointers in this post. I don't know why it required a reboot, but all is good now.

Comment: What happens if you remove `nofail` from the `fstab` line?

Comment: Could you paste output of `blkid` ?

Comment: @StephenKitt that doesn't make a difference unfortunately

Comment: @mrc02_kr I've added the output to the post

Comment: you could try checking `journalctl -b`. if systemd thinks the device does not exist / is removed, it has a mis-feature where it will unmount the disk. i guess you could also check `systemctl list-units *.device` and see if there is a systemd device unit for /dev/sdc1.

Comment: also please make a habit to specify the OS distribution and version.  This would have indicated whether you are using systemd or not :-).

Comment: also did you try running `sudo df` ? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445225/why-df-h-not-showing-partition-mounted/453694#453694

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/597525 or directly see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1741

Answer (score 27):

The most likely reason is that file system is mounted, as the mount commands reports, but then `systemd` thinks it knows better and unmounts it before you can see it.

You could use another directory as a mount point, or find out from the logs why it is unmounted.

Comment: So true, It got fixed by `systemctl daemon-reexec`. How dare systemd make such assumptions and **decide to** do something? That's why enterprise grade distributions should stop supporting it as the only available init daemon.

Comment: Oh god, thank you, this was my case too. `systemd` is too smart...

Comment: This helped in my case too, on Raspberry PI OS.

Comment: This would be a lot more interesting if you had any explanation of what the problem actually was.

Comment: @EML True. But the ways of systemd are mysterious and beyond mere mortals.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, after the volume successfully mounted, `systemd` was immediately unmounting it for me (thanks to RalfFriedl for his answer which gave me the hint I needed).  This was verifying by running `journalctl -f` and mounting the volume, and observing the log.

The fix was to add the volume to the `/etc/fstab` file and **then reboot**.  [`systemd` will adjust itself at boot time based on the fstab](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) file, so it will no longer unmount your volume.  Note that you *can* configure mounts directly in systemd, but [the `/etc/fstab` is the correct place for humans to do it](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html):

> Mount units may either be configured via unit files, or via /etc/fstab
> (see fstab(5) for details). Mounts listed in /etc/fstab will be
> converted into native units dynamically at boot and when the
> configuration of the system manager is reloaded. In general,
> configuring mount points through /etc/fstab is the preferred approach
> to manage mounts for humans. For tooling, writing mount units should
> be preferred over editing /etc/fstab. See systemd-fstab-generator(8)
> for details about the conversion from /etc/fstab to mount units.

My `/etc/fstab` entry.  Your `UUID` will surely be different:

```
UUID=5ffa5f54-6ff0-47dd-97f8-b3446d58b239    /mnt    ext4 
   defaults,noatime,nofail    0    2
```